# Help me understand why my edit was rejected when the subsequent one was accepted?

Tags: discussion, tags, disputed-review-audits, rejected-edits

Can someone explain to me why [my suggested edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10075031)? It shows one of the rejects coming from [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) with the following comment:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

How is the system process user able to come to this conclusion?

When I look at the [latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33494124/revisions) from [Sk93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148424/sk93), which came after mine, it has basically the same change as mine, but was accepted.  Why was my edit rejected and the other one accepted?

Comment: That was a decent edit, IMO. But Makoto's reasoning below applies. Unfair things (undeserved downvotes, undeserved nasty comments or fights, rejected edits, unaccepts, etc....) happen to everyone on SO from time to time, it's best to shrug them off.

Comment: This is probably the 3rd or 4th time it has happened to me.  At this moment, I am more worried about why this meta question is receiving so many down votes...

Comment: @Eric : 1 - Votes don't cost rep on meta, so people are throwing them more freely. 2 - 2 up, 4 down isn't "so many downvotes". 3- Possible a lot of people who downvoted you are doing so because this is asked relatively frequently, so you could've found the "reject and edit" in other questions? 4- Tim is locked out.... AGAIN :( poor guy can't keep his keys

Comment: It hasn't happened to me *yet* but I can see how discouraging it can feel

Comment: @xPeke - leave spare keys with a neighbour.

Comment: Unrelated to the edit at hand, but while I personally appreciate edits that add explicit syntax highlighting hints where they're desperately needed, [I'd encourage you to be more descriptive with your edit suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2108154). You don't have to worry too much once you gain full editing privileges, but a descriptive edit summary is particularly important in the review process (robo-reviewers notwithstanding).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The user selected the "Reject and Edit" option, which caused your edit to be rejected on the spot, and allowed them to edit it instead.  It seems that they then copied over your changes and applied them as their own.

Personally I would have opted to improve the edit, since you did an otherwise okay job with it. Note that adding the tags in the question does not help its readability at all; there you'd want to add the official product name.  You also left in noise at the bottom.

We can't answer "why" someone would do that; maybe they felt like you didn't deserve the 2 rep from the edit.  Or they felt like it wasn't enough to warrant the rep.  But...I wouldn't take it personally.

Comment: Reading the edits, I think *Approve and edit* was the best course of action. Cause you can't reject an edit and use those changes as your own, technically it could be considered plagiarism

Comment: It seems like this is something that stackexchange should look at addressing in the future.

Comment: @xPeke:  In my opinion they should have, since again - there really wasn't a lot of bad to that edit.  I don't know if there's anything technical that could be done to prevent something like this in the future though, not because it's hard to detect, but perhaps because the juice isn't worth the squeeze.

Comment: And I know that more than likely he didn't mean to, I think that sometimes we get caught in routine and perform actions automatically and don't notice these little things.

Comment: Know what'd be great? A way to express agreement without having to litter the thread with comments to that effect.

Comment: a few more of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31374482) @Eric and you won't have to sit in the "accept my edit" queue. Nice job on that one

Comment: @BoltClock I totally agree with your comment! That would be great!

Comment: @BoltClock If you want to propose a new feature for meta you should create a feature request question rather than asking for it in a comment.

Comment: @Servy I genuinely can't tell if you're trolling more subtly than I was or if you've suffered a catastrophic sarcasm detector fail. If the former, I guess you win.

Comment: @MarkAmery It was the former.

Answer (score 8):

I probably<sup>†</sup> would have rejected the edit because of the added tag markdown. It's hard to see in the suggested edit (both the markdown, and rendered views) so here's the original text:

> I just upgraded our SonarQube installation to 5.1.2 and did some changes to our LDAP setup to require group membership og new group for access.

and the modification from the suggested edit:

> I just upgraded our [sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sonarqube) installation to 5.1.2 and did some changes to our [ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ldap) setup to require group membership in new group for access.

I think that the tags make the post look more cluttered, and it's not something I've seen used anywhere else on the main site.

---

*<sup>†</sup> I say probably because I didn't see this in the context of a review, and have seen the other answers here, so I'm not seeing this with a lot of additional context.*

Answer (score 1):

It was rejected because Sk93 chose to reject and edit it. The edit was accepted because he/she has more than 2k rep and thus the edit didn't need to go through the review queue.

Comment: Do people who use my answer also receive the +2 reputation for doing the edit?

Comment: @Eric:  If they're above 2K rep, no.  They don't receive any rep for edits.