# Someone stole my edit, should anything be done about it?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

The other day one of my edits was rejected:

[image: screenshot]

*[unless you're on a 4k monitor or something, you'll have to enlarge the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rnzU.png)]*

On the left is my rejected failure of an edit, rejected by Community and "purple user". On the right, "purple user"'s *awesome* edit which doesn't need a review because he's over 2k rep.

The things "purple user" changed in the edit made it *worse*, in my opinion!

Of course, I searched around for any other similar cases. And I found a lot of them. However, only [one of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309400/help-me-understand-why-my-edit-was-rejected-when-the-subsequent-one-was-accepted) had the same problem I was facing, from 2015.

1. Can I or should I do anything about? Is there even something *to be done* about it?

   (note that I'm not asking broadly for opinions, I'd like to know if there's a site mechanic or feature that allows me or encourages me to do something about it. maybe a flag of sorts)
2. Did that Community user rejection show up *because* of "purple user"'s decision to reject? If so, then can some users (such as 2k+ rep) decisively reject or approve an edit request? If not, then how and why did that Community user vote show up?

   (I have searched around for these things, but as I mentioned, none of the questions I've found had the same situation as mine. Most were about OP and the person editing at the same time)

Comment: I think that person should have clicked "Improve Edit" since they used a lot of your edits. But it's nothing to be upset about. I wouldn't say their edit is that bad. In fact it looks like they made the image clickable so you can see a full-sized version. The only thing they should have done is change the alt tag of the image. And the answer to your number is yes to all questions. I think Community is a bot that just rejects and accepts based on the majority vote. And since users can decisively reject&edit or improve&edit, it rejected since purple user rejected&edited

Comment: So to sum it all up, don't get overly attached to your edits and edit "score"

Comment: Yeah, it's not like they matter all that much, what bothered is the fact that I didn't actually do anything _wrong_, it was sheer luck ;\

Comment: @KodosJohnson The Community user rejects an edit, when a reviewer hits “Reject & Edit”, _not_ based on the majority vote. About the edit suggestion: most notably, the “thanks in advance” noise was left intact. This should have been deleted. The reviewer most likely rejected the suggestion because of this alone.

Comment: @Xufox I've seen this happen a few times and I don't get it. Why should "Thanks" be deleted? It doesn't clutter the question and it expresses OP's gratitude. It's equivalent to a `:)`, it's polite

Comment: @MatheusAvellar [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/289905)

Comment: @Matheus the thanks is implicit, and if you truly want to express gratitude, upvoting works. Also.... Am I really getting THAT old? ":)" is... POLITE, nowadays?

Comment: @Xufox mike4ty4 brings up [my point](http://i.imgur.com/RNdyOsk.png) too. It doesn't affect a question to the point of unreadability. I defend that it should be up to the editor to decide

Comment: While you may disagree.... If you know the community's standard is to prune that.... Then yeah, not removing it in your edit leaves you at risk of someone who truly believes this is noise to reject your edit.

Comment: @MatheusAvellar: The issue here wasn't "Hi,", but "thanks in advance!" So that objection doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Side note: if you want "do something about it" - there is a good chance that question deserves deletion (like any other average SO question :( ). Unleashing Meta effect may delete the question along with your edit and you can keep you spotless edit history... Also making substantial improvements on good posts instead of spellcheck edits would be more welcome route from the site's point of view.

Comment: I see your point, but at the same time, I can't make up what I think OP wanted. If the question is not specific enough, that's a job for the comment section to solve. I can't just edit in specificity if I myself am unsure of what that is. What I _can_ do is remove some clutter (to which I may start including "thank you"'s from now on) to help other users understand a question more easily

Comment: @MatheusAvellar if question is incomplete/unclear to remove clutter instead of edit you should downvote/vote or flag to close/add comments. If question does not get into on-topic state your edits either never will be seen by any future visitors (due to lack of them) or simply get lost due to removal of the post (search for "roomba" on Meta). This know as (technical term :) ) ["polishing turd"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=polishing+turd) and while can be successful (http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/polishing-a-turd-minimyth/) it requires enormous effort.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the screenshot there is no improvements whatsoever - so looks rightfully rejected.

- "Can anybody help me?" is not a form of question that is welcome on SO - [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/303544)
- Editing "thanks in advance" to be better spelled rather then removing sends completely wrong message to author of the post - [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)
- "my code is not working" is not explanation of the problem. If you can gather details from comments - edit them in, otherwise delaying edit till there are details is preferable.

Comment: If the edit was unecessary / lacked improvements, then why would it be posted minutes later pretty much exactly the same? That's my question. I can't possibly predict what the user needs if they don't provide enough information. Question improvement requests should be made in the comments. All I can do as an editor is clarify what is already there, so that it takes _less time_ for others to read it and assess if OP provided enough information or not; and then answer or comment based on what they decide.

Comment: @MatheusAvellar edits that require reviews are expected to make questions noticeably better. Such edits ask for up to 5 people to look at the change and carefully review it. Changes that marginally improve the post (minor tags, minor spelling) and the rest of the problems untouched (like missing problem explanation) simply waste time of those 5 people. If you like fixing spelling - get to 2K reputation and edit posts without reviews.

Comment: @MatheusAvellar additionally "reject" sends good signal to editor that particular types of changes are either not welcome or incomplete. Based on your question and comments you were not aware of some SO policies (like remove "thank you" notes) and thus reject let you learn them.

Comment: The edit requests queue can't even be compared to the Close Votes queue, with 9k suggestions waiting for review. So "waste time of those 5 people" on as tiny of a queue as it is doesn't count as a valid argument to me. Plus, the actual [official guide to editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) states as valid reasons _"To fix grammar and spelling mistakes"_ and _"To correct minor mistakes"_. Additionally, nothing on that guide says _"remove "thank you" notes"_, I just found out about that today because I asked this question

Comment: @MatheusAvellar I really hope you are not serious suggesting that it is ok for people to spend more time reviewing minor edits because other tasks that can be done at the same time (like reviewing close votes) are bigger anyway and will not be done quickly.

Comment: No! Haha what I'm saying is that there is an abundance of people reviewing edit queues frequently. I'd agree with your point if this was a "Close Votes" matter, due to its already huge queue, but as an edit request, it really doesn't clog the queue significantly.

Answer (score 9):

The one thing I always notice about these "someone stole my edit!" questions is the idea that somehow, the reviewer that made the edit is *profiting* off your hard work setting up the edit, and in a way that makes it easy for them. Neither of those is really true. Sure, some people (including myself) like to have nice high edited post counts, but for that, it makes no difference whether we Improve Edit, Reject Edit, or just find something else to edit. And Reject Edit, in particular, requires about as much work to copy over or redo useful edits as they were to make originally.

So I hate to break it to you, but 99 times out of 100, the sad truth is that the reviewer sincerely did not think your edit was good enough to make the cut. And so, because of the work they put into editing the post instead, *it didn't*. They had no personal animus, no greedy desire for cheap credit, nor any other base motive. Just the impersonal judgement that the edit wasn't really all that hot. Your failure to gain rep, credit, and suggested edit stats didn't benefit them at all.

Specifically, as others have mentioned, making the image linkable and removing the fluff were the main differences, although there were also some grammar tweaks. I don't know that I personally would have Rejected; I might have Improved instead. But the reviewer wasn't wrong to do so. (And in particular, deliberately fixing grammar or spelling in obvious fluff like "thx en advantag" really grinds my gears in a way that simply leaving it alone doesn't at all.)

Comment: I really don't mind about the reputation and whatnot. I just wanted it to be fair. If 90% of the edit was good (and copied over), why does it deserve a rejection? I try not to remove as much of the original question as possible (or at least, I used to, I'll rethink that strategy after this). So yeah, I would correct "Thank you"'s or alike because it's part of the message OP intended to send. But anyway, _that_ discussion is already open somewhere else